# Vector space and subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces, definition

So I know you can't have a empty vector space as if $V=\emptyset$ there is no zero vector anyway, and that you could have a empty subset of a vector space (as {$\emptyset$} subset of any set), but how come a empty subset of a vector space could also be a subspace? And how is $\operatorname{Lin}(\emptyset)=\{0\}$? I'm confused, sorry if my question is basic , Thanks.

Comment: Is your confusion that the empty set is taken to a *basis* for the trivial subspace (which is not empty)?

Comment: yeah , and that a empty set could be a subspace of a vector space correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The empty set is not a subspace of a vector space.   Possibly you read an incorrect definition somewhere.

Comment: @fredgoodman yeah I thought so, but there was a proof question about lin(s) where S subset of vector space V  and you have to prove its smallest subspace of V that contains S, they consider case when S=$\phi$

Comment: The smallest subspace containing the empty set is the smallest subspace altogether, namely $\{0\}$.   But I think you may be confused because of a convention that may not have been made explicit:  a sum of no elements is taken to be zero, and a linear combination of no elements is taken to be zero.   This is to avoid clumsy special cases in various arguments.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum

Comment: @fredgoodman , thanks , yeah these definitions confused me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty set is *not* a vector space, since $(\emptyset,+)$ has no identity element.